# Post value with getJSON function to php

Tags: javascript, php, charts, getjson

I need to send the new date to the PHP page to update the chart based on the user's choice.

this my js code when load page :

```
$.getJSON("chart.php", function (data) {

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
data: [
{                              
 indexLabel: " {y}",
 indexLabelFontSize: 16,
 dataPoints: data
  }
  ]
 });

chart.render();
 });
```

and this my php code :

```
     include("config.php");
     
    $data_points = array();  

 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT sub, main, SUM(amount) AS total FROM data GROUP BY sub, main order by total desc LIMIT 15");
    
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {        
            $point = array("label" => $row['sub'] , "y" => $row['total']);
    
            array_push($data_points, $point);        
        }
    
        echo json_encode($data_points, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

I use the chart from  https://cdn.canvasjs.com/canvasjs.min.js

When the user selects a date from the calendar, I want to update the chart. How do I do that?

Comment: You could send it in the URL as a query parameter: `chart.php?date=2023-12-23` and then use `$date = $_GET['date'] ?? '{some default date}';` and use that in your query. Just make sure you use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) when using user input to make it as safe as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I do not prefer using the Get method.
also date send from index html page to php chart page.
I found a way to send values like this
$.getJSON('chart.php', { date: 'newdate' }, function(response) {
..
});
, but I did not know how to receive them in PHP

Comment: `$.getJSON()` is a shortcut for making GET requests. If you pass parameters they will be added to the URL just like I showed and you can get those using the `$_GET`-variable. If you really want to post data instead, use [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType) instead.